# How to show fixed video background in section?

Tags: css

I want to have a youtube video fixed in the background of the page and to be show only in a specified section this is my html :

```
<section style="height: 600px;background: none;" id="section-bg">
    
    
</section>

 <video class="sleep-video" autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

and this my CSS:

```
.sleep-video {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

when i change z-index to 0 the video is shown fullscreen but i want it to be displayed only when i scroll through the section with id="section-bg".

Comment: have u tried to use position sticky?

Comment: for which element ?

Comment: for the element you want to stick), the video

Comment: already tried that no luck there is a problem somewhere of z-index i think

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the section you don't want the video in `position: relative` (actually try also taking the video inside the section because you might have the body positioned relative) and give the video position absolute starting from the `bottom: 0`  of the relative section. See if that helps

Comment: `<section style="height: 600px;position:relative;" id="section-bg"> 
 <video class="sleep-video" autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</section>                                                                                                                                                                        
 .sleep-video {
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to write `code` in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will benefit you:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,p {margin: 0}
.cover-body { /* step 1 */
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;  /* step 2 */
}
.sleep-video {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -2;  /* step 3 */
}
.content {  /* step 4 */
    background: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<section style="height: 300px;background: none;" id="section-bg">
    
    
</section>

 <video class="sleep-video" autoplay muted loop>
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<div class="cover-body"></div>
<div class="content">
<p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```